# Как авторизоваться в MongoDB, используя MongoClient?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Решил защитить свою бд и подключить аутентификацию для удалённого доступа. Но не смог найти информацию об аутентификации через MongoClient, только если использовать mongoose, чего я не хочу. Ещё был вариант авторизация в url `const url = 'mongodb://user:pass@localhost:27017/dbname';` но этот вариант не работает. MongoDB v.4.0.6

```
var db = null;
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/';

MongoClient.connect(url, {useNewUrlParser: true}, function(err, dbr) {
  if (err) throw err;

  db = dbr.db("my-db");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашёл решение проблемы. Так как я зарегистрировал пользователя через консоль, который управляет несколькими базами данных, то для подключения нужно указывать самую первую зарегистрированную базу данных, а потом уже подключаться к нужной базе данных. Очень долго ломал над этим голову, но интуиция не подвела :)
Вот код:

```
var db = null;
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/';

MongoClient.connect(url, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  auth: {username: "admin", password: "pass"},
  authSource:'first_db'
}, function(err, dbr) {
  if (err) throw err;
  db = dbr.db('necessary_db');
});
```

И вот ещё один вариант, который мне показался неудобным и устаревшим:

```
var db = null;
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const url = 'mongodb://user:pass@localhost:27017/?authSource=first_db';

MongoClient.connect(url, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
}, function(err, dbr) {
  if (err) throw err;
  db = dbr.db('necessary_db');
});
```